# TypeScript - data structure and organisation to limit verbose code blocks

Tags: typescript

In my TypeScript module, I have a series of array structures where each of them will hold separate data.

```
var monthlySheetP = [
    ['Year', 'Month', 'Program', 'Region', 'Market', 'Country', 'Started', 'Completed']
];
var monthlySheetV = [
    ['Year', 'Month', 'Program', 'Region', 'Market', 'Country', 'Started', 'Completed']
];
var monthlySheetT = [
    ['Year', 'Month', 'Program', 'Region', 'Market', 'Country', 'Started', 'Completed']
];
var monthlySheetB = [
    ['Year', 'Month', 'Program', 'Region', 'Market', 'Country', 'Started', 'Completed']
];
var monthlySheetU = [
    ['Year', 'Month', 'Program', 'Region', 'Market', 'Country', 'Started', 'Completed']
];
var monthlySheetPV = [
    ['Year', 'Month', 'Program', 'Region', 'Market', 'Country', 'Started', 'Completed']
];
var monthlySheetPT = [
    ['Year', 'Month', 'Program', 'Region', 'Market', 'Country', 'Started', 'Completed']
];
var monthlySheetVT = [
    ['Year', 'Month', 'Program', 'Region', 'Market', 'Country', 'Started', 'Completed']
];
var monthlySheetPVT = [
    ['Year', 'Month', 'Program', 'Region', 'Market', 'Country', 'Started', 'Completed']
];
```

I iterate through some other data and start populating these arrays in the following way;

```
if (dealer.buService == 'B') {
    monthlySheetB.push(cells);
} else if (dealer.buService == 'U') {
    monthlySheetU.push(cells);
} else if (dealer.buService == 'PVT') {
    monthlySheetPVT.push(cells);
}
```

Array declaration block at the top appears to be too verbose. Is there more elegant way of declaring these data structures?

Comment: @JohnWeisz - structure of the array will be same for all instances but they will hold separate sets of data.

Comment: var meta =    ['Year', 'Month', 'Program', 'Region', 'Market', 'Country', 'Started', 'Completed'];

    var monthlySheetP = [].push(meta);

A better way would be to create a function that generate an array containing the  redundant metaData

Comment: You can also add the meta data at the end of all logic using array.unshift(['Year', 'Month', 'Program', 'Region', 'Market', 'Country', 'Started', 'Completed'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a object to store your data:

```
var monthlySheet = {
    'P': ['Year', 'Month', 'Program', 'Region', 'Market', 'Country', 'Started', 'Completed'],
    'V': ['Year', 'Month', 'Program', 'Region', 'Market', 'Country', 'Started', 'Completed'],
    'T': ['Year', 'Month', 'Program', 'Region', 'Market', 'Country', 'Started', 'Completed'],
    'B': ['Year', 'Month', 'Program', 'Region', 'Market', 'Country', 'Started', 'Completed'],
    'U': ['Year', 'Month', 'Program', 'Region', 'Market', 'Country', 'Started', 'Completed'],
    'PV': ['Year', 'Month', 'Program', 'Region', 'Market', 'Country', 'Started', 'Completed'],
//...
};
```

An then work with that object:

```
monthlySheet[dealer.buService].push(cells);
```